# Game Kit Unreliably Sent Packets Getting Corrupted?

Tags: struct, game-center, gamekit, packet, latency

I am working on a two player game using Game Center.  For every move of the local character I send this struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    PacketTypes type;
    TurnType moveType;
    int moveCount;
    BOOL ate;
} MovePacket;
```

I send it unreliably for efficiency, but whenever there is higher latency BOOL ate gets whacked.  On the receiving end ate may equal all kinds of crazy numbers like -32, 100, -98.  I tried sending it reliably and this does not happen, but then the opponent on each device becomes noticeably jerkier.

I can't figure out why this is happening.  The other variables are always correct.  I did some logging to make sure that I am sending it correctly.  And yes I am.  The variable sent is correct and the variable received is incorrect from the same packet.

Any ideas?